# How do we use structs?

Tags: c, struct

The main problem I'm having is having so many parameters, which I just want to get rid of, and yes I do not understand the logic of structs. However, it is becoming a bit more clear...

**EDIT**
So cHao wanted me to use a specific case so here is an example I cooked up:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //Top coord. of the square
    int top_x1 = 0;
    int top_y1 = 10;
    int top_x2 = 10;
    int top_y2 = 10;

    //Bottom coord. of the square
    int bottom_x1 = 0;
    int bottom_y1 = 0;
    int bottom_x2 = 10;
    int bottom_y2 = 0;

    //Left coord. of the square
    int left_x1 = 0;
    int left_y1 = 0;
    int left_x2 = 0;
    int left_y2 = 10;

    //Right coord. of the square
    int right_x1 = 10;
    int right_y1 = 0;
    int right_x2 = 10;
    int right_y2 = 10;

    parameter(top_x1, top_y1, top_x2, top_y2, bottom_x1,
              bottom_y1, bottom_x2, bottom_y2, left_x1,
              left_y1, left_x2, left_y2, right_x1, right_y1,
              right_x2, right_y2);
}

parameter (int top_x1,int top_y1,int top_x2,int top_y2,int bottom_x1,
              int bottom_y1,int bottom_x2,int bottom_y2,int left_x1,
              int left_y1,int left_x2,int left_y2,int right_x1,int right_y1,
              int right_x2,int right_y2)
{
    int totalParameter, topSide, bottomSide, leftSide, rightSide;

    topSide = (top_x2 - top_x1);
    bottomSide = (bottom_x2 - bottom_x1);
    leftSide = (left_y2 - left_y1);
    rightSide = (right_y2 - right_y1);

    totalParameter = (topSide + bottomSide + leftSide + rightSide);
    printf("%d\n", totalParameter);

}
```

and if I try using structs...

```
#include <stdio.h>>

struct coordinates
{
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
};

int main()
{
    struct coordinates top;
    struct coordinates bottom;
    struct coordinates left;
    struct coordinated right;

    //Top line of the square
    top.x1 = 0;
    top.y1 = 10;
    top.x2 = 10;
    top.y2 = 10;

    //Bottom line of the square
    bottom.x1 = 0;
    bottom.y1 = 0;
    bottom.x2 = 10;
    bottom.y2 = 0;

    //Left line of the square
    left.x1 = 0;
    left.y1 = 0;
    left.x2 = 0;
    left.y2 = 10;

    //Right line of the square
    right.x1 = 10;
    right.y1 = 0;
    right.x2 = 10;
    right.y2 = 10;
}

parameter(top, bottom, left, right)
{
    int totalParameter, topSide, bottomSide, leftSide, rightSide;

    topSide = (top.x2 - top.x1);
    bottomSide = (bottom.x2 - bottom.x1);
    leftSide = (left.y2 - left.y1);
    rightSide = (right.y2 - right.y1);

    totalParameter = topSide + bottomSide + leftSide + rightSide;
    printf("%d\n", totalParameter);
```

}

Doesn't work though, any help? :P
Error I get is: "Request for member 'x1' in something not a structure of union.
For all the x and y coords.

Comment: Screw structs.  You have 20 items that you use identically.  Use an array.

Comment: Yes, but this was just an example, what if they were not used identically, would arrays still be a good idea?

Comment: If they're not used identically, then a struct *might* make sense.  It'd depend on whether the things you're passing could actually be considered as one thing with various properties.

Comment: If you want a recommendation for the real case, then show the real case.

Comment: I added the real case

Comment: In the real case, i'd recommend (a) that you have two structs, `square` and `point`; but also (b) that you read up about C99's "compound literals", which make structs much easier to work with; and (c) that you meditate a bit on what exactly it means for something to be a "square".  (You don't need separate lines for each side, as the sides by definition will always meet at a corner.  You just need corners.  But since all sides are defined in terms of each other, you don't even need all the corners -- you can define a square by the coordinates of any *two* corners, chosen consistently.)

Comment: John, once asked and after receiving answers, we ***cannot*** mutilate the original post. Please, refer to the [help] or ask a support Question at [meta] in case of further doubts.

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef struct _foo
{
    int x1, x2, x3,..., x20;
} foo;

int add(const foo *pBar)
{
    return pBar->x1 + pBar->x2 + pBar->x3 + ... + pBar->x20;
}

int main()
{
    // declare and initialize the struct
    foo bar = { 1, 2, 3, ..., 20 };

    // an alternative way of initializing the struct:
    bar.x1 = 1;
    bar.x2 = 2;
    bar.x3 = 3;
     :
    bar.x20 = 20;

    int total = add(&bar);
}
```

Comment: "I do not wish to use global variables." -- OP

Comment: Eesh, it's demoing _how_ to do it.  I'll edit the global out.

Comment: For reference, you could also say `foo bar = { 1, 2, 3, ... 20 };`.

Comment: Yes, that would be a cleaner way to initialize the struct.  I'll add that.

Comment: @Carey Gregory, Actually I like it the way it is.  If OP is passing the struct around to functions he needs to know how to access members anyway.

Comment: Actually the cleanest way to initialize it is probably a designated initializer. `foo bar = {.x1 = 1, .x2 = 2, .x3 = 3, ..., .x20 = 20};`

Comment: @Étienne Does C support designated initializers?  At least it doesn't in my compiler.

Comment: @CareyGregory It's a C99 feature.

Answer (score 1):

**Refers to general using of struct, not the technical side:** (because it seems to me that you do not understand the logic in it)

You should use **struct** for group of variables they part of one thing.

For example, struct point (to represent point in in space) will contain int for X and int for Y.

You should use **array** for group of variables they the relation between their is serial.

For example: students in class, since you want to do same actions on each student in sequence.